Using a pico and a photoresistor to measure light intensity
I've recently been trying to do an experiment requiring me to measure light intensity.
I didn't have the necessary equipment, but I did have a photoresistor and a Raspberry Pi Pico, so I tried connecting them and using the analogue pins on the Pico to measure the voltage.
I have now done the experiment, and the results were quite accurate. The Pico could accurately measure differences in light intensity, and there was a significant difference in the reading when I put a bright light source in front of it.
My problem is that I can't really figure out how it works. I connected the photoresistor in series when I should've connected it in parallel. Furthermore, in my code (found below), I have only defined the analogue input pin, not the output, yet it still gets a voltage reading. I'm now writing up a report and I can't explain why it works, it shouldn't!
Can anyone please point out if I'm missing something very obvious that I should change, or explain why it works?
For reference, here is my code:
import machine

# The higher the n, the more accurate the reading is (it reads it n times and takes the average).
def read(n):
    mean = []
    temp = 0
    for i in range(n):
        mean.append((3.3/65535)*(machine.ADC(machine.Pin(26)).read_u16()))
    for i in range(len(mean)):
        temp = temp + mean[i]
    return (temp/len(mean))
# I know I could just add the reading to temp and then divide by n in the end, but I was tired.

while True:
    print(1/read(4000)) 
# 4000 is the highest amount of times before the pico processor gives up.

Here is my circuit schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Thanks!

The python environment may initialize the pins in some way. You need to figure out how. Then with that knowledge you can have an answer why it seems to work even if it shouldn't.

I found something here*, that says Pin 10 (GPIO 7) is set to input with a pull-up resistor. I still don't understand how this would supply the ADC with voltage...

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=200601


One problem with this is that it depends on the input impedance of the ADC.
Basically what it appears is happening is that GP7 is initialized as an input with pullup, so there's an internal resistor from there to 3.3 V so there's going to be voltage on that pin. The photo-resistor and ADC input impedance form a voltage divider from that voltage, and the divider voltage is what the ADC reads. So let's the ADC input impedance is 100 kΩ and the photo-resistor and pullup total 50 kΩ, the ADC would then read 2/3 of 3.3 V or 2.2 V.
But how well defined is the input impedance? Will it be the same for every Pico? What happens if the light level changes rapidly adding an AC component to the voltage? Is the voltage from GP7 going to change at all? All of these things can affect the reading.
A better way would be to have the photo-resistor and a fixed resistor form the divider and feed it from a stable reference voltage, then buffer and possibly scale the divider voltage with an opamp so the ADC is fed from a low impedance.
Also I believe the ADC input on these needs to be initialized to make it high impedance with something like adc = Pin(31, Pin.IN) but you might want to research that a bit to make sure.

Could I still use the results from the experiment to show the trend? As you said, there are a lot of factors which can lead to different figures, but can I still write about the trend or are all the results redundant and completely unreliable?

@SpyridonManolidis Well, the results would be valid for that particular hardware setup, and they may work for an identical setup using a different Pico but I wouldn't rely on it. Also photo-resistors will have some variation from one to the next, so you need to take that into account if your circuit is going to be duplicated, typically there would be some means of calibrating but that all may be beyond what you need if this is just a one-off for a class.
